# Site does not show when deployed to azure app service

Tags: azure, .net-core, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a simple "Hello World!" .NET Core MVC 3.1 web application to an Azure App Service using the Azure Portal Deployment Center.

I created a my application using .Net Core version 3.1. (Visual Studio 2019 only has version 3.1 in the drop down, not 3.0.)

Visual Studio 2019 create wizard dropdown:

[image: Framework version dropdown in Visual Studio 2019]

However this is not yet supported in the Deployment Center. You can select a runtime stack 3.1 (LTS) when adding creating the App Service Plan, but when you try and create a CI/CD pipeline with the Deployment Centre, it gives an error: "source.buildConfiguration.version: Property 'source.buildConfiguration.version' has invalid/unsupported value 'LTS'"

If I downgrade my web application to a version 3.0, and create the App Service/deployment pipeline with 3.0 using the Azure Portal Deployment Centre (building from my Azure Repo), it says the deployment has been successful, but it still shows the default site, not my "Hello World!" site.

Azure Devops Services indicates that the deployment has been successful:
[image: Deployment success screen]

Therefore, I expect to see my "Hello World!" site:
[image: Hello World site]

However, it still shows default site:
[image: Default Azure App site]

Given that there are no error messages, I'm not sure how best to debug what has gone wrong with the deployment. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: just wondering ...do you have routes? Have you tried specifying the full route to your hello world? E.g. mysite.azurewebsites.net/home/hello

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio No, I don't have any custom routes set up. It's just an out-the-box web application. When I go to localhost:5001, it gives me the "Hello World!" homepage. I don't need to go to /home.

Comment: I've also tried setting up a "Hello World!" site using .NET Core 2.1, and creating a deployment pipeline using the Deployment Centre in the Azure Portal. When I create the deployment pipeline, it shows that it has run correctly in the Releases tab in Azure Devops Services, but I still just get the default App Services page. So it doesn't seem to be related to the .NET framework version.

Comment: Also, I'm able to deploy the site using Visual Studio > Publish > Publish to App Service. This issue is specifically that the auto generated deployment from Azure Portal > Deployment Centre does not work. It says the deployment has been successful, but it isn't showing any changes.

Comment: Have you checked the project under `wwwroot`?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/

Comment: When I deploy using Visual Studio (which works), I get the Kudu dashboard. When I deploy using the Deployment Centre > Azure Pipelines, I get a success message, but the site doesn't deploy. The scm site says Azure App Service, and under wwwroot it is still the default site. There are no deployments in the Deployment Logs.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue today... The solution was to change the 
Startup Command (dotnet "myApp.dll" instead of dotnet run "myApp.dll") 
under Configuration - General Settings in the App Service.

[image]

You might also check the Log Stream in your App Service for additional errors.

I also had to adjust the CD pipline task "Deploy Azure App Service" in Azure Devops to the Same Startup command.

Comment: Same problem with rails, same analogous solution with command: rails server

Comment: "MyApp" is the name of the project, in case you're wondering. If your project's name is 'project1' then the command would be `dotnet project1.dll`.

Comment: Same issue with ASP.NET Core 6 project in GitHub and Azure App Service. The automatic CD generated a couple of runtime json files and it didn't know which one to run until I followed the above. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change .NET version to v4.8. Azure by default set it to v3.5, even though I selected 4.8 in the AppService wizard. My website uses v4.6.1.

[image]

Comment: I know longer have access to the above repository, and this may no longer be an issue. But if anyone is able to confirm any of the answers above, I will accept that solution as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And also, you have to change the document order in the configuration settings - default documents, in order to work and show the project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ste7Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I did it using the bicep.

So here is my solution -
https://github.com/worldpwn/azure-linux-web-app-minimal-example

It is dotnet 7 deployment to azure web app linux.